# How can I do a border which have a tv screen shape?

Tags: css, border, border-radius

This is what I want, a green border as a tv screen shape:
[image]

This is really hard.

Can you help me?

I tried css3 code of tv screen shape:

```
a{display:block; width: 200px; height:150px; border: 1px solid #B0C523;
    border-radius: 80%/30%;}

a:before{content: "";
    border-radius: 30%/80%;
    left: -4%;
    right: -4%;
    border: 1px solid #B0C523;
    top: 11%;
    bottom: 11%;
    background-color: transparent;}
```

but it's not right.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with Width Height and the radiuses.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grayrec {
  background-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 60px;
}

.rec {
  width: 220px;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  font: 50px helvetica bold;
  border: 2px solid hsl(70, 50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 23% 23% 23% 23% / 30% 30% 30% 30%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grayrec">
  <div class="rec">
    <a>HOME</a>
  </div>
</div>
```